# Configure OpenCV to use in java does not work

Tags: java, macos, opencv

Currently I try to use OpenCV in my Java application. In maven I used the newest library

```
<groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
<artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
<version>4.5.1-2</version>
```

and I installed OpenCV with

```
brew install opencv
```

I also found the installation in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.3/
```

but when I try to run my java application with

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
```

i got

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java453 in java.library.path: [/Users/me/Library/Java/Extensions, /Library/Java/Extensions, /Network/Library/Java/Extensions, /System/Library/Java/Extensions, /usr/lib/java, .]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2660)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:827)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1871)
    ...
```

I use IntelliJ and in my run configuration I also added as program argument

```
-Djava.library.path=/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.5.3/lib
```

but when I read out in this program the java.library.path I got:

```
properties: /Users/me/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
```

so I miss the added path...

I also do not found any symbol called **opencv_java451** or **opencv_java453**

can anyone help me? Tanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can find your machine's **java.library.path** directory.
In my MacBook, it was /Library/Java/Extensions.
Copy the dylib file into it.